# Comparing numbers pulled from MySQL using If statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, vbscript, asp-classic

Pulling 2 decimal values from MySQL and trying to use a very simple if statement:

```
if subtotal < minval then DO THIS else DO THIS
```

It always thinks subtotal is smaller even though it might not be. `IsNumeric` confirms both these values are numeric. If I use `minval=19.99` instead of pulling from the database it works.

The code for retrieving `minval` looks like this:

```vb
Set rscontrol = db.Execute("select * from websitecontrol ")
minval = FormatNumber(rscontrol("minordervalue"))
```

Comment: Check the type of the value pulled from the database (`TypeName(minval)`). Most likely you're comparing two strings, or a string to an actual number. Checking with `IsNumeric` doesn't really help here, because it evaluates if the expression can be evaluated as a number, which is also true for a string containing just a number. For further help: show your code.

Comment: Both values are stored as decimal(19,2) in MySQL. Typename shows subtotal as double, which I believe is correct for a numeric but minval shows as string so I guess there's my problem, can you tell the code it's a numeric?

Answer (score 1):

[`FormatNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws343esk%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is a function for formatting a value for display. It returns a formatted string.

```
>>> n = 1.25
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(n)
Double
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(FormatNumber(n))
String
```

*Never* use formatting functions *unless* the result is intended for being displayed.

Change

```vb
minval = FormatNumber(rscontrol("minordervalue"))
```

to

```vb
minval = rscontrol("minordervalue")
```

If that still doesn't help you can force the value to a double using the [`CDbl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftekwwt0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function.

```vb
minval = CDbl(rscontrol("minordervalue"))
```

Beware that the function expects the decimal point as it's configured in your system's regional settings.

Comment: set rscontrol=db.execute("select * from websitecontrol ")
minval=formatnumber(rscontrol("minordervalue"))

Comment: @user3417410 See updated answer. Also, please put that kind of information in your question in the future. This time I took the liberty of doing it for you.